Understanding the error covariance of pooled regression model
I am reading Econometric Analysis by Greene (7th edition, 2011). On page 350, he discusses the random effects regression model:
$$
\begin{aligned}
y_{it} &= x'_{it} \beta + E[z'_i \alpha] + \left[ z'_i \alpha - E[z'_i \alpha]\right] + \varepsilon_{it} \\
&= x'_{it} \beta + a + \varepsilon_{it} + (c_i - E[c_i | X_i]) \\
&= x'_{it} \beta + a + \varepsilon_{it} + u_i \\
&= x'_{it} \beta + a + w_{it}
\end{aligned}
$$
The book then says that the unobserved heterogeneity (i.e. $z'_i\alpha$) induces autocorrelation: $E[w_{it}w_{is}] = \sigma^2_u$ when $t \ne s$.
I don't believe I see this. If we take expectations wrt time $t$ and noting that $E_t[w_{it}] = \omega_i$
$$
\begin{aligned}
Cov_t(w_{it}, w_{is}) &= E_t [(w_{it} - \omega_i)(w_{is} - \omega_i)]\\
&= E_t(w_{it}w_{is}) + T \omega_i^2 \\
&= E_t[(\varepsilon_{it} + u_i)(\varepsilon_{is} + u_i)] + T \omega_i^2 \\
&= E_t[\varepsilon_{it} \varepsilon_{is}] + E_t[u_i^2] +  T \omega_i^2 \\
&= T(u_i^2 + \omega_i^2)  \qquad \text{ for } t \ne s
\end{aligned}
$$
Obviously, from the above
$$
\begin{aligned}
E_t(w_{it}w_{is}) &= E_t[(\varepsilon_{it} + u_i)(\varepsilon_{is} + u_i)] \\
&= E_t[\varepsilon_{it} \varepsilon_{is}] + E_t[u_i^2] \\
&= Tu_i^2  \qquad \text{ for } t \ne s
\end{aligned}
$$
How did they get $\sigma^2_u$?

Your derivation introduces expectations over time for $t$ and $s$, but Greene’s result is not derived this way. Instead, Greene’s derivation looks at the cross-time covariance for a given individual $i$, without involving time-averaging.
In Greene's random effects model derivation, the total error term is given by:
$$
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
w_{it} = u_i + \varepsilon_{it}
\end{equation}
$$
The induced autocorrelation comes from $u_i,$ which is constant across all time periods for a given $i$.  This correlation is reflected in the line:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Cov(w_{it}, w_{is}) \qquad\ \text{ for } t\ne s
\end{aligned}
$$
Decomposing $w_{it}$ and using (1), results in:
$$
\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
Cov(w_{it}, w_{is}) = Cov(u_i+\varepsilon_{it}, u_i+\varepsilon_{is})
\end{equation}
$$
$\varepsilon_{it}$ is independent of both $u_i$ and $\varepsilon_{is}$, so (2) reduces to:
$$
\begin{align}
Cov(w_{it}, w_{is}) &= Cov(u_i, u_i)
\\&=Var(u_i)
\\&=\sigma_u^2
\end{align}
$$
